# Test django forms raised ValidationError

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm struggeling to test my forms that raise a validation error.

My test looks like the following:

```
    def test_register_password_strength(self):
        form_params = {'first_name': 'John',
                       'last_name': 'Doe',
                       'email': 'john@doe.com',
                       'password': 'a',
                       'password_confirm': 'a',
                       'g-recaptcha-response': 'PASSED'}
        form = RegisterForm(form_params)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())

        try:
            form.clean_password()
            self.fail('Validation Error should be raised')
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.assertEquals('pw_too_short', e.code)
```

And the form raises the `ValidationError` in the following way:

```
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if len(password) < 7:
            raise ValidationError('Password must be at least 7 characters long.', code='pw_too_short')

        return self.cleaned_data.get('password')
```

`self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())` asserts correctly to false, but when I try to call `form.clean_password()`, I get the following error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.

`self.cleaned_data` has no element named `password` after `form.is_valid()` was called.

Is there another way of testing the `ValidationErrors` other than calling `is_valid()`?

Comment: You should use `Form.has_error(field, code=None)` instead : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_error

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen this method, it works perfectly fine :-)

Comment: I posted the answer for you ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using :

```
    try:
        form.clean_password()
        self.fail('Validation Error should be raised')
    except ValidationError as e:
        self.assertEquals('pw_too_short', e.code)
```

Consider using `Form.has_error('password', code='pw_too_short')`

More info here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_error